# Deducing $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}s=-\phi\kappa\mathrm{d}s$ from an evolving curve

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, plane-curves

Let $M$ be an interval on the real line or a smooth $1$-manifold diffeomorphic to $S^1$ and let $X:M\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a plane curve evolving according to
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}X=-\phi N,$$
where $N$ is the unit normal and $\phi:M\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$. If $\kappa$ is the curvature defined by
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}T=-\kappa N\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}N=\kappa T,
\end{cases}$$
where $T$ is the unit tangent and $s$ is the arc length parameter, I'd like to show the arc length element $\mathrm{d}s$ satisfies
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}s=-\phi\kappa\mathrm{d}s,$$
using
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}=\phi\kappa\frac{\partial}{\partial s}.$$

**Idea:** If we interpret $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}$ as a vector field on $M$, then $\mathrm{d}s$ can be seen as a $1$-form dual to $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}$ that gives $$\mathrm{d}s\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\right)=1.$$

Comment: Isn’t this the answered by Deane’s answer to your previous question? In the case of curves, the mean curvature is up to sign $\kappa$.

Comment: @Mr.Brown Sadly, I didn't really make out Deane's argument on the more general case, so I decide to start with a simpler case.